# Как узнать имя тега по ссылке ?

Tags: html, javascript

Как узнать имя тега по ссылке ?

var someTag = document.getElementById("someID");

Как узнать имя тега по ссылке someTag ?

Comment: Открываете консоль JavaScript например в Chrome, вводите туда  

    var someTag = document.getElementById("someID");
Жмете клавишу Enter, после этого вводите в консоль  

    someTag.
автодополнение кода автоматически покажет список всех свойств и методов объекта, просмотрите внимательно их- в будущем может пригодиться. Среди всей этой кучи Вы увидите `tagName`, то есть так:  

    someTag.tagName

Comment: спасибо. отличное дополнение !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть свойство [TagName](http://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties#%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-nodename-%D0%B8-tagname)

Comment: element.tagName - javascript чувствителен к регистру